# JDBCTemplate queryForMap for retrieving multiple rows

Tags: java, spring, oracle10g, jdbctemplate, spring-3

Can I use `queryForMap` if there are multiple rows returned by the query.

For a single row, the below code works fine.

```
public Map<String, Object> retrieveMultipleRowsColumns(String deptName){
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForMap("SELECT DEPT_ID,DEPT_NAME FROM DEPT WHERE DEPT_NAME = ?", deptName);
}
```

How to modify this for multiple rows?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle 10g ; is it database dependent?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `queryForList` [see the javadoc for full details](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29).  It returns `List<Map<String,Object>>`

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> retrieveMultipleRowsColumns(String deptName){
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT DEPT_ID,DEPT_NAME FROM DEPT WHERE DEPT_NAME = ?", deptName);
}
```

Comment: A list of maps is not very useful.

Comment: Incorrect, a list of maps can be very useful depending on the context.

Comment: @EricaKane I'm intrigued as to why you would think that.

Answer (score 27):

I know this is really old, but there is a  much simpler way to do this if you're looking for a map.

Simply implement the ResultSetExtractor interface to define what type you want to return. Below is an example of how to use this. You'll be mapping it manually, but for a simple map, it should be straightforward.

```
jdbcTemplate.query("select string1,string2 from table where x=1", new ResultSetExtractor<Map>(){
    @Override
    public Map extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,DataAccessException {
        HashMap<String,String> mapRet= new HashMap<String,String>();
        while(rs.next()){
            mapRet.put(rs.getString("string1"),rs.getString("string2"));
        }
        return mapRet;
    }
});
```

This will give you a return type of Map that has multiple rows (however many your query returned) and not a list of Maps. You can view the ResultSetExtractor docs here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html

Answer (score -3):

```
public <T> List<T> queryForList(String sql,
                            Class<T> elementType,
                            Object... args)
                 throws DataAccessException
```

Description copied from interface: JdbcOperations Query given SQL to create a prepared statement from SQL and a list of arguments to bind to the query, expecting a result list.
 The results will be mapped to a List (one entry for each row) of result objects, each of them matching the specified element type.

Specified by:`queryForList` in interface JdbcOperations ,
`Parameters:sql` - SQL query to execute elementType - the required type of element in the result list (for example, Integer.class)`args` - arguments to bind to the query (leaving it to the PreparedStatement to guess the corresponding SQL type); may also `contain SqlParameterValue` objects which indicate not only the argument value but also the SQL type and optionally the scale Returns:a List of objects that match the specified element type Throws: DataAccessException - if the query failsSee Also:JdbcOperations.queryForList(String, Class), SingleColumnRowMapper